# 'swiper-container' is not a known element on version 9

Tags: angular, swiper.js

After updating to swiper v9.0.3 it showing

`'swiper-container' is not a known element:

1. If 'swiper-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'swiper-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`

Was trying to update swiper in my angular project

Comment: Did you import the SwiperModule in your app.module.ts?

Comment: Yes, but not worked. It was working on version 8

Comment: I've read a lot of docs and this one helped me. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75413910/19893499

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem: according to the page "Migrating from ion-slides to Swiper.js" 9 in the official documentation the schema CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA can be declared globally in app.module.ts, but for me it works only when I declare it in it the module file for each page, e.g., home.module.ts.

So just try to declare "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" in your module file, where you want to use it.

Comment: I emphasize the point that is th esolution for me : _it works only when I declare it in it the module file for **each page**, e.g., `home.module.ts` ._

Answer (score 1):

Swiper Angular components have been removed in v9. If you want to use v9, you need to change your Angular components to web components.

You can start with adding CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to your app module's schema.

https://swiperjs.com/migration-guide-v9#swiper-angular

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [AdmiralBang's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77080678/2334352), I've noticed adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to your module file doesn't eliminate the error. You'd have to restart your CLI and `serve` the application again.

Also, this works, whether you added it globally or within the template's module file