# Angular 14 swiper 9

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I need to use swiper in my app but its not working, ther is an error

```
error NG8001: 'swiper-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'swiper-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'swiper-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the @NgModule.schemas of this component to suppress this message.
```

so I do the following

```
npm install swiper
import {CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
// import function to register Swiper custom elements
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
// register Swiper custom elements
register();
```

in my app.module.ts

and added CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA to schemas

and added

```
<swiper-container>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

like it says in [swiperjs.com](https://swiperjs.com/element) documentation

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem but only when I build with `"aot": true` in  the angular.json.
If I use ionic serve or ng serve it's working. 

Is it the case for you?

Comment: --> with that solution it's working konw : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77080678/10967760

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the custom elements schema in the module that holds the component where you intend to use it:

your module file (could be app.module or any module):

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';


@NgModule({
  schemas: [..., CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
  ...
})
```

Then you need to call `register()` in  `app.component.ts` not app module as you stated you did in your question

app.component.ts:

```
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';

register();

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
```

Then you should be able to use swiper components in your template.

Reference [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/slides)

Comment: There is no "swiper/angular" in swiper 9, in swiper 9 it uses Swiper Element [check here](https://swiperjs.com/angular)

Comment: Thanks, good catch. I updated my answer for swiper v9 and above

Comment: Hey @HovhannesManukyan did this work?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as @HovhannesManukyan but only with the `ng build --prod` and not with `ng serve`. I follow the doc that you mention. At some point I tried to transform the classic component to a new standalone component, but it's leading to some tricky problem in our app that I don't want to adress for now.

Comment: @lascapi maybe you should open a new question that lists your issues specifically