# How to use the swiper 9 pagination with Angular

Tags: angular, web-component, swiper.js, custom-element, viewchild

I'm actually migrating to swiper 9.

I had already faced some problems and asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75326426/how-to-use-swiper-9-with-angular) about the swiper 9 migration

Some of the answers help me moving forward.
But now I'm trying to use the pagination

I used to import the pagination like follow

```js
import SwiperCore, { Pagination, Swiper } from 'swiper'

// ...

  @ViewChild('swiperRef', { static: true })
  private _swiperRef: ElementRef | undefined
  swiper?: Swiper

// ...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    SwiperCore.use([Pagination])

    this.swiper = this._swiperRef.nativeElement.swiper
  }
```

But the pagination isn't working.

For what I see on their [doc](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#install-from-npm) I should do the following

```js
  import Swiper, { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';

  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    // configure Swiper to use modules
    modules: [Navigation, Pagination],
    ...
  });
```

But I do not understand, I don't have any `.swiper` element, and I don't which to declare any. Also, I have multiple swiper on the same page, so I would wish to target only the specific `_swiperRef` one.

Is it somehow in a proper way doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite hard to understand but I did it.

1. Avoid the swiper initialized himself

```html
<swiper-container #swiperRef init="false"> 
  <!-- You slides --> 
</swiper-container>
```

2. You do not need to use the `SwiperCore` anymore

```js
@ViewChild('swiperRef', { static: true })
  private _swiperRef: ElementRef | undefined
swiper?: Swiper

options: SwiperOptions = {
  slidesPerView: 1,
  zoom: true,
  enabled: true,
  pagination: true,
  autoHeight: true,
}

ngOnInit() {
  const swiperEl = this._swiperRef.nativeElement
  Object.assign(swiperEl, this.options)

  swiperEl.initialize()

  this.swiper = this._swiperRef.nativeElement.swiper
}
```

3. Should just work out of the box