# Why is event binding not working when using Swiper Element in Angular?

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I am using the Swiper Elements Web Component in Angular and following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75413910/1188074) where an event is bound in the template using Angular like event binding in the template.

Note I have not seen this syntax in the official [docs](https://swiperjs.com/element#events) or examples.

```
<swiper-container
  (slidechange)="slideChange()"
>
```

The `slideChange` function is never called.

Should this syntax work and if so, why is it not working here?

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-nsa3zk?file=src%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.html,src%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/element#events) you should prefix all the event with `swiper`

**Try this:**

```
<swiper-container
  slides-per-view="auto"
  space-between="30"
  (swiperslidechange)="slideChange()"
>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://cataas.com/cat" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://cataas.com/cat" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://cataas.com/cat" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://cataas.com/cat" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://cataas.com/cat" /></swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide><img src="https://cataas.com/cat" /></swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>
```

**[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7ewkcq?file=src%2Fcarousel%2Fcarousel.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

change `slidechange` to `swiperslidechange`

Comment: Argh missed that. Thanks, I have accepted the other answer as it provides more context but appreciate your input.